# Activity is stopped when starting new activity with a custom Camera implementation

Tags: android, android-activity

When starting a new activity that has a custom Camera implementation, the main activity is closed (onStop is called with IsFinishing() set to true).  When calling other activities this does not happen.  I am working under the assumption that the main activity is being closed due to a low memory condition, as I can start other activities without error.  How do I prevent the main activity from being shutdown when I call the camera activity, as there is a service started in the main activity that will be re-used for the camera activity?

Code that calls new activity:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Context, MyClass.Snapshot.class));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `startActivityForResult` to signal to Android that you want your Activity to be delivered a result.

Comment: startActivityForResult produces the same results (onStop is called in main activity).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think keeping the MainActivity from closing is a viable option.  You stated that the reason is related to the MainActivity starting a service.  Well really anything with a a reference to a Context can start a service.  You could use a Singleton quite easily.  I think keeping the Main Activity around is not necessary, and not a good practice since Android can always decide something like this.  One thing you might try is to startSticky the Service and see if that makes a difference.  Let us know.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is my own stupidity.  Had a bunch of commented code below my startActivity call, but I forgot to comment out 1 line towards the bottom... That line was calling onFinish() which would explain everything.

Thank you everyone for trying to diagnose my stupidity.